# Assaltar X Roubar

Tags: significado, português-brasileiro, gramática

Qual é a diferença entre **roubar** e **assaltar**?

Será que roubar significa tirar completamente alguma coisa sem permissão e assaltar significa tirar alguma coisa de algum lugar ou de alguém sem permissão?

Exemplos:

> Roubaram o carro.

> O banco foi assaltado.

Mais uma dúvida:

Posso falar que:

> Assaltaram o banco!

?

Comment: sim, podes falar que "assaltaram o banco". Pelo que sei, não envolve diferença de "lugar" ou "alguém". Na realidade, acho muito comum ouvir "assaltaram o banco" e "roubaram o banco".

Comment: Se suficientemente souberes português: com todo o respeito, recomendo veres, num dicionário, ambas as palavras. O Google tem um dicionário próprio, por exemplo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Assaltar](https://dicionario.priberam.org/assaltar) carrega consigo o sentido do uso de violência. Muitos dicionários omitem a questão de subtrair algo de alguém. Me parece que o ato de violência é mais importante para o sentido da palavra assalto do que o ato de se apossar de algo que pertença a outrem.

Já [Roubar](https://dicionario.priberam.org/roubar) é um sinônimo de [Furtar](https://dicionario.priberam.org/furtar). Palavras estão ligadas ao ato de se apossar de algo que pertence a outrem, mas carregam também o sentido de algo conduzido em segredo, às escondidas, sem que o dono/portador tenha ciência do que está ocorrendo.

No uso coloquial, aqui no Brasil, as pessoas usam "roubar" com qualquer sentido (tanto o de furto quanto o de assalto). Mesmo que roubar se refira *a pegar algum objeto*. Muitos usam "Eu fui roubado", quando na realidade o que foi pego *foi um objeto que pertence a pessoa*, e não *a pessoa em si*.

Comment: Jorge (vou chamar-te de "Jorge" porque não gosto de não chamar alguém pelo nome), posso estar muitíssimo errado no que direi a seguir. Acho que "fui roubado" pode ser um caso de metonímia; ou seja, em vez de falar "o que tenho foi roubado", falar "fui roubado".

Answer (score 1):

Se o seu intuito é somente transmitir a outra pessoa que levaram um objeto de um terceiro sem permissão, poderia usar qualquer um dos dois.

Quando trabalhei na área de segurança ouvi muito que não se existe assalto, mas sim roubo e furto. Porque?

O [assalto](https://dicionario.priberam.org/assalto), como está na outra resposta, tem muita relação com a violência, o ataque surpresa. Pode se transformar em um crime, mas nem sempre envolve o roubo.
Esta palavra também pode ser um [gênero de filme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heist_film) na qual um grupo de pessoas planejam um roubo. Não sei dizer se os filmes e séries de *assalto* que acabaram trazendo este termo ao cotidiano.

Se reparar geralmente crimes contra bancos são planejados, rende as pessoas, usam armas como nos filmes, então é comum ver nos noticiários brasileiros os tais assaltos aos bancos.

Tecnicamente:

O **roubo** é necessário envolver violência e ameaça geralmente verbalmente e também feita com armas. Não importa se é um roubado lugar ou objeto.

Tirar algo de algum lugar sem permissão, se não houver violência, nem ameaça com arma pode ser considerado o **furto**. É só lembrar da palavra furtivo, de forma discreta. Mesmo assim vai ser comum ouvir:

> Nossa! Roubaram meu celular e não vi.

> Roubaram a casa de fulano, ainda bem que não tinha ninguém lá.

> Assaltaram a loja de madrugada.

Ninguém viu, não houve violência, nem ameaça, na verdade houve um furto, mas vai ser raro ouvir alguém falar que *furtaram* algo ou alguém.

Parando pra pensar, pelo menos da minha vivência é comum sim, usar assalto para imóveis e roubo para outros bens, não é via de regra, e só para compartilhar mesmo.

A questão de não existir assalto como termo técnico para subtração de bens, mas roubo e furto é importante para: ler contrato de seguro de bens, entender boletim de ocorrência da polícia (geralmente vão colocar roubo ou furto), e claro para a área de direito, entender as leis, não vai ter assalto referindo a roubo.
Furto e roubo estão nos artigos 155, 156 e 157 do [Código Penal brasileiro](http://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/decreto-lei/del2848.htm).

Logo, há diferença no significado da palavra assalto e roubo, mas na prática para a comunicação em geral pode ser usado qualquer um dos dois para se referir à subtração de bens.

Answer (score -1):

A diferença entre roubo e assalto é que o roubo é sem arma, e o assalto é com arma.

Comment: É um bom começo de resposta, mas acho que não está correto: se alguém te bater para te roubar dinheiro, não é roubo - é assalto... mesmo não havendo arma envolvida. Aliás, daí o conceito de "assalto à mão armada" precisar de especificar "mão armada": porque há assaltos sem arma.